# Azure Active Directory login on Windows 10 Universal app works in Phone but not on Desktop

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, windows-10, win-universal-app

I'm building a Windows 10 Universal App. I'm trying to sigin user using Azure Active Directory.

Active Directory uses a library called ADAL (Active Directory Authentication Library). Latest stable version is ADAL v2.18.206251556 which is incompatible with Windows 10. So I'm using a pre-release ADAL v3.5.207081303-alpha.

When I'm trying to sigin on Windows 10 Phone (including emulator and physical device), I'm able to successfully login. But when I try to login on Windows 10 Desktop, I'm getting the following error.[image: Error_Screen]

Is that a problem of ADAL? How can I fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When windows 10 is trying to do a WIA/NTLM, following capabilities need to be entered into application's Package.appxmanifest:

```
<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <uap:Capability Name="enterpriseAuthentication"/>
    <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
    <uap:Capability Name="sharedUserCertificates" />
</Capabilities>
```

This will then solve the problem.